# BackboneJS RSS feeds

Tags: backbone.js, rss

I want to fetch RSS feeds and display them in my Backbone App. Can I do something like this?:

```
function (App, Backbone) {

    var Rss = App.module();

    Rss.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: 'rss',
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'all', this.render)
        },
        serialize: function() {
            return this.collection ? this.collection.toJSON() : [];
        }
    });
    Rss.RssCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function() {
            return 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml';
        }
    });

    Rss.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:  'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml',
        defaults: {
            title: '',
            description: '',
            pubdate: ''
        }
    });

    return Rss;
}
```

Then my HTML template looks like:

```
<p>{{title}}</p>
<p>{{description}}</p>
<p>{{pubdate}}</p>
```

but I get `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`. So, how can I avoid this? And is my Backbone Approach even correct?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How are you testing? Try running a local server and fetching the page via http:// rather than file://

Comment: @JoelCornett Right now just running a localhost...

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting indicates that due to [CORS policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), your browser is not able to fetch resources on 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml' from the page/domain under which this app runs.

You could work around that CORS problem by adding the `feeds.bbci.co.uk` URL to a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header, but that won't fix everything either because your browser won't accept hat you inject content from another source.

Your Backbone approach could work if you use(d) a service like [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/) (I created it!) which is able to convert the feed into JSON with callback that can be invoked with the new data.